# Error Loading JSON Data to DynamoDB local

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-dynamodb

I have the downloadable DynamoDB local(currently working).
I have read their documents and their example code is working.

I created the Users table with the name "Users"

Here is the UsersCreateTable.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.7.16.min.js"></script>

    <script>
AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/',
  // accessKeyId default can be used while using the downloadable version of DynamoDB.
  // For security reasons, do not store AWS Credentials in your files. Use Amazon Cognito instead.
  accessKeyId: "fakeMyKeyId",
  // secretAccessKey default can be used while using the downloadable version of DynamoDB.
  // For security reasons, do not store AWS Credentials in your files. Use Amazon Cognito instead.
  secretAccessKey: "fakeSecretAccessKey"
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

function createUsers() {
    var params = {
        TableName : "Users",
        KeySchema: [
            { AttributeName: "id", KeyType: "HASH"}
        ],
        AttributeDefinitions: [
            { AttributeName: "id", AttributeType: "N" }
        ],
        ProvisionedThroughput: {
            ReadCapacityUnits: 5,
            WriteCapacityUnits: 5
        }
    };

    dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "Unable to create users table: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "Created users table: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
        }
    });
}

    </script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="createTableButton" type="button" value="Create Table" onclick="createUsers();" />
    <br><br>
<textarea readonly id="textarea" style="width:400px; height:800px"></textarea>


</body>
</html>
```

I have prepared the sample JSON data for our Users Table.
I have modified their MoviesLoadTable.html file and converted it to UsersLoadTable.html which uploads JSON data to the DynamoDB local, in order to load my JSON Users Data.

When I try to load my JSON data I get these errors on console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 497
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at FileReader.r.onload (UsersLoadData.html:31)
r.onload @ UsersLoadData.html:31
FileReader (async)
processFile @ UsersLoadData.html:53
```

And here is the UsersLoadData.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.7.16.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/',
  // accessKeyId default can be used while using the downloadable version of DynamoDB.
  // For security reasons, do not store AWS Credentials in your files. Use Amazon Cognito instead.
  accessKeyId: "fakeMyKeyId",
  // secretAccessKey default can be used while using the downloadable version of DynamoDB.
  // For security reasons, do not store AWS Credentials in your files. Use Amazon Cognito instead.
  secretAccessKey: "fakeSecretAccessKey"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

function processFile(evt) {
    document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML += "Importing users into DynamoDB. Please wait..." + "\n";
    var file = evt.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
        var r = new FileReader();
        r.onload = function(e) {
            var contents = e.target.result;
            var allUsers = JSON.parse(contents);

            allUsers.forEach(function (user) {
                document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML += "Processing user id: " + user.id + "\n";
                var params = {
                    TableName: "Users",
                    Item: {
                        "id": user.id,
                        "info": user.info
                    }
                };
                docClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML += "Unable to add user: " + count + user.id + "\n";
                        document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML += "Error JSON: " + JSON.stringify(err) + "\n";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML += "Loading succeeded(id): " + user.id + "\n";
                        textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
                    }
                });
            });
    };
        r.readAsText(file);
    } else {
        alert("Could not read users data file");
    }
}

    </script>


    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="file" id="fileinput" accept='application/json' />
    <br><br>
<textarea readonly id="textarea" style="width:400px; height:800px"></textarea>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', processFile, false);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I searched for the error and could not find a satisfying solution.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file has invalid format:
[image]

Here you have fixed JSON:

```
    [{
        "id": 1,
        "info": {
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "Smith",
            "city": "NY",
            "birthday": "26/07/1996",
            "activities": [
                "Basketball",
                "Cinema",
                "NightOut"
            ],
            "badges": [
                "Friendly Player",
                "Basketball Pro"
            ],
            "reviews": [
                "Came to event on time",
                "Good basketball player",
                "I didn' like him",
                "Didn't show up on time"
            ],
            "connections(id)": [
                2,
                3,
                4
            ],
            "events": [{
                    "place": "Some Place",
                    "date": "10/10/2017",
                    "time": "18:00",
                    "activity": "Basketball"
                },
                {
                    "place": "Another Place",
                    "date": "13/10/2017",
                    "time": "21:00",
                    "activity": "Cinema"
                },
                {
                    "place": "Third Place",
                    "date": "19/10/2017",
                    "time": "22:00",
                    "activity": "NightOut"
                }
            ]
        }
    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "info": {
            "name": "Adam",
            "surname": "Williams",
            "city": "San Francisco",
            "birthday": "Unknown",
            "activities": [
                "Tennis",
                "NightOut"
            ],
            "badges": [
                "Friendly Player",
                "Tennis Pro"
            ],
            "reviews": [
                "Adam is the best",
                "Best tennis player ever",
                "Don't play tennis with this guy"
            ],
            "connections(id)": [
                1,
                3,
                4
            ],
            "events": [{
                    "place": "Tennis Place",
                    "date": "01/03/2018",
                    "time": "20:00",
                    "activity": "Tennis"
                },
                {
                    "place": "Nightout Place",
                    "date": "03/03/2018",
                    "time": "20:00",
                    "activity": "NightOut"
                }
            ]
        }
    },

    {
        "id": 3,
        "info": {
            "name": "Juan",
            "surname": "Martinez",
            "city": "New Mexico",
            "birthday": "Unknown",
            "activities": [
                "Basketball",
                "NightOut"
            ],
            "badges": [
                "Pro Basketballer",
                "Night Owl"
            ],
            "reviews": [
                "Juan is crazy",
                "This guy can drink more than an elephant"
            ],
            "connections(id)": [
                1,
                2,
                4
            ],
            "events": [{
                    "place": "Basketball Court",
                    "date": "25/02/2018",
                    "time": "16:00",
                    "activity": "Basketball"
                },
                {
                    "place": "Nighclub",
                    "date": "03/03/2018",
                    "time": "19:00",
                    "activity": "NightOut"
                }
            ]
        }
    },

    {
        "id": 4,
        "info": {
            "name": "Charles",
            "surname": "Jackson",
            "city": "Pennsylvania",
            "birthday": "Unknown",
            "activities": [
                "Coding",
                "Lecture"
            ],
            "badges": [
                "Lecturer of Lecturers",
                "Code Master"
            ],
            "reviews": [
                "Best lecturer in the world",
                "Codes are amazing"
            ],
            "connections(id)": [
                1,
                2,
                3
            ],
            "events": [{
                    "place": "Pennsylvania University",
                    "date": "05/03/2018",
                    "time": "13:00",
                    "activity": "Lecture"
                },
                {
                    "place": "Pennsylvania University",
                    "date": "05/03/2018",
                    "time": "16:00",
                    "activity": "Coding"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Remove "event 1", "event 2", "event 3" keys from arrays. Fixed json you have above